# Segmentation fault: Using strtok, system calls. C programming

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, system, system-calls, strtok

I am currently trying to strtok two times in order to tokenize all the commands passed by a file. The first round of tokenization works but then I get a segmentation fault. What could it possibly be? I've tried to make all the arrays smaller because I thought it was a memory issue. This is also programmed in C and I don't get any errors or warnings.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        char content[100];
        int fd;
        ssize_t bytes = 0;
        fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
        int i = 0;

        char* token;
        const char a[2] = "\n";
        const char b[2] = " ";
        char storage[20][20];
        char temp[20][20];
        bytes = read(fd, content, sizeof(content)-1);
        close(fd);

        if(fd < 0)
        {
                write(1, "File doesn't exist\n", 19);
                return 1;
        }


        token = strtok(content, a);
        strcpy(storage[0],token);
        printf("%s\n",storage[0]);

        while(token != NULL)
        {
        i++;
        token = strtok(NULL, a);
        strcpy(storage[i],token);
        printf("%s\n",storage[i]);
        }

      token = strtok(storage[0],b);
        strcpy(temp[0], token);
        printf("%s\n",temp[0]);
        i = 0;

        while(token != NULL)
        {
        i++;
        token = strtok(NULL, b);
        strcpy(temp[i],token);
        printf("%s\n",temp[i]);

        }





return 0;

}
```

This is the output I am getting:

```
/bin/ls -l 
/bin/cat command.txt 
/usr/bin/wc -l -w command.txt 
??
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: Debugger is your friend.

Comment: This code is clearly broken. You invoke `strtok`, then blindly assume it succeeded and use its resulting pointer as the source for regular `strcpy`. Only *later* do you test the result of the token for `NULL`. The same problem exists in multiple places, both in and out of the loops. Just think about this: `strtok` can return NULL. So.. where do you *not* check that between the time you invoke `strtok` and the time you use its result?

Comment: How many lines are there in the file ? Also my many tokens per line ? File with number of lines more than 20 and lines with more than 20 tokens can make your program access memory not belonging to the process.

Comment: @WhozCraig I've added print lines after every command. It seems to output correctly but for some reason, always has one more iteration than it's supposed to have which makes it print out random values.

Comment: @vmaroli around 71 lines, if that we're the case, how could i fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>     strcpy(storage[0],token);
>     printf("%s\n",storage[0]);
> ```

You do the same in 4 or 5 occasions. You need to check if  `token` is not NULL. Otherwise your program is just the UB

```
if( token)
{
    strcpy(storage[0],token);
    printf("%s\n",storage[0]);
}
else
{
    /* do something if token is NULL */
}
```

you can also reorganize your loops (this the first one as an example):

```
    token = strtok(content, a);
    i = 0;

    while(token != NULL)
    {
    strcpy(storage[i],token);
    printf("%s\n",storage[i++]);
    token = strtok(NULL, a);
    }
```

Comment: That's for the first strtok and after that I say while( token != NULL), would this pass as checking if token is not NULL?

Comment: @beatsbyse for all I afraid , Take a pen  & paper and follow the program flow. your while conditions do not protect you against the NULL poiter dereferencing.

Answer (score 0):

Segmentation Fault occurs when the your program is trying access memory areas beyond what is allocated to your program.  Since you have have only allocated array of size 20 for storage and storing more than that, that is a problem. Also you have allocated array of size 20 for storing tokens per line which may be not be enough depending on the number of tokens you have per line. Apart from these, like others mentioned you also need to check if the strtok is returning null. Trying to de-refence a null pointer can also cause segmentation fault